# data.location not working in aws-sdk-js-v3

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk-js-v3

I'm using MEAN stack to build a chatapp and the user needs to upload a profile image at some point so i decided to use s3 to store the images and get the image URLs stores in my mongodb database so they are displayed in the fronted from the database. I I'm able to successfully upload and image to the bucket and see it in my dashboard but it doesn't update in my database, so when debugging I found out the response from the s3.send(command) doesn't have the location property, so I'm wondering how i could get the uploaded image url. Please help me !!

Here's the part of my code that handles the image upload:

```
exports.uploadProfileImage = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const userId = req.params.userId;

    // Use multer upload middleware to handle file upload
    upload.single('image')(req, res, async (err) => {
      if (err) {
        // Handle multer file upload error
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Multer : Failed to upload profile image' });
      }

      // Check if file exists in the request
      if (!req.file) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: 'No file found' });
      }

      const file = req.file;

      const buffer = await sharp(file.buffer).resize({height: 300, width: 300, fit: "contain"}).toBuffer()

      // Upload the file to S3
      const command = new PutObjectCommand({
        Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: `${userId}-profile-image.jpg`,
        Body: buffer,
        ContentType: file.mimetype,
      });
      const data = await s3.send(command)
      console.log(data)
      
      // Update the user's profile image URL in the database
      const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
        userId,
        { profileImage: data.Location },
        { new: true }
        );

      res.status(200).json({ user });
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to upload profile image' });
  }
};
```

When i try to console.log(data.location) i get undefined, and when I log console.log(data) i get this:

```
{
  '$metadata': {
    httpStatusCode: 200,
    requestId: '20CW7DGKDN5CH2KX',
    extendedRequestId: 'hwnVMq2To+JzIKufMt3t3lOjGfwQz3Ltkb9uU1Tc/nWyU4KbdKS61TM9Hicyyy5FTGM0SzFc4ys=',
    cfId: undefined,
    attempts: 1,
    totalRetryDelay: 0
  },
  ETag: '"2af8d9fd67798fe823c88b06b057b766"',
  ServerSideEncryption: 'AES256'
}
```

Please can anyone help me solve this ?